# how to add "no record found" in this approach using mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

How to add no record found if the result is empty. this approach search the last record of the customer if he is new then the result is empty. but I want to add a word "no record found"

```
   $when = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: 700;">When:</span>';
   $app1 = $_GET["app_id"];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE app_id = $app1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1")  or die(mysql_error());
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $ctr= '(','1-1508-0010'. ')';
    echo ' ';
    echo '<span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500;">'.$row['request'].'</span>';
    echo ': ';
    echo $row['description'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $when,' ';
    echo $row['datereq'];
    echo ' ';
    echo '<br>';
  }
  echo '<br>';
```

Comment: watch out for SQL Injection. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
{
  // no record
}
```

**N:B:**

> mysql_ is officially deprecated (as of PHP 5.5. Will be removed in PHP 7.). try to use mysqli_ instead

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($query) === 0)` sounds better

Comment: @Raptor thanks for the suggestion. i have updated my answer :)